# Rstudio server on Google Cloud without adding another user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-permissions, rstudio-server

I am trying to run the Rstudio Server on a virtual Instance running Ubuntu on Google Cloud. Given that by default, a user on google cloud does not have a sudo password on Google Cloud, connecting to the server with username/password is not directly available.

Several tutorials (see [tuto 1](https://sookocheff.com/post/r/deploying-r-studio-to-compute-engine/), [tuto2](https://grantmcdermott.com/2017/05/30/rstudio-server-compute-engine/) and [tuto 3](https://yuhuisdatascienceblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/setting-up-r-studio-server-on-google.html)) suggest creating a new user, which will come with username/password, hence allowing to use standard username/password with Rstudio Server. This solution raises however several issues, like access/write permission, different R package folder, difficulties to connect to new user, etc.

Is there a way to connect to the Rstudio server without creating a new user? I guess a possible way would be to add a password to the default user in Google Cloud, although this seems also difficult per se ([old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/DYfDOndtRTU/u_3kzNPqDAAJ) on this)?

Thanks!